# sudo rabbitmqctl status gives Error and also takes time to responde

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I get this error when i run `sudo rabbitmqctl status`  on an on-prem server specifically on rhel8

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@xxxxx'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.
 
Most common reasons for this are:
 
* Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)

* CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)

* Target node is not running
 
In addition to the diagnostics info below:
 
* See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more

* Consult server logs on node rabbit@xxxxxx

* If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools
 
DIAGNOSTICS

===========
 
attempted to contact: ['rabbit@xxxxx']
 
rabbit@xxxxx:

  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on xxxxxxx

  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic

  * can't establish TCP connection to the target node, reason: timeout (timed out)

  * suggestion: check if host 'xxxxxxxx' resolves, is reachable and ports 25672, 4369 are not blocked by firewall
 
Current node details:

* node name: 'rabbitmqcli-401-rabbit@xxxxx'

* effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq

* Erlang cookie hash: gvMlNMNDWrRk2xONh+tqWQ==

 Documentation: Table of Contents
 — RabbitMQ
```

Erlang version = `Erlang/OTP 25`
Rabbitmq version = `3.12.12` latest

How can i fix this error?

I attempted to establish TCP connections to the ports `25672, 4369, 5671, and 15672` using the `nc` command, and the connections were successful.

Additionally, I pinged the hostname/IP address to verify if it is reachable.